# Css Animation Opacity Regarding :after pseudo class

Tags: html, css, animation

I have the following code that I created, it's kinda like a loading animation.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 17px 17px 45px #d1d1d1;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 180%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: orangered;
}

.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d3e6e6;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  animation: pulse 1s linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #71cbcb;
  border-bottom-color: #71cbcb;
  border-width: 4px;
  top: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  position: absolute;
  animation: spinny 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spinny 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spinny {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2) rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <p class="title">Spinner</p>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

I want the "pulse" animation to only affect the innter circle and not the borders.  For the borders, I used `:after` thinking that it would be seperate from the actual circle but I guess it's not because even though the pulse animation is in the css of `.circle` and not `.circle:after` it still affects it.

Would appreciate any help. Im kinda stuck :D

Answer (score 1):

i have same change in css  please   `border-width:0px;`

```css
body {
            background-color: #fafafa;
        }

        .container {
            width: 700px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: white;
            margin: 0 auto;
            box-shadow: 17px 17px 45px #d1d1d1;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .title {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 180%;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 20px;
            color: orangered;
        }

        .circle {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: #d3e6e6;
            margin: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: 60px;
            animation: pulse1 1s linear infinite alternate;
            -webkit-animation: pulse1 1s linear infinite alternate;
        }

        .circle:after {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            height: 60px;
            width: 60px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: none;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-top-color: #71cbcb;
            border-bottom-color: #71cbcb;
            border-width:4px;
            top: -9px;
            left: -9px;
            position: absolute;
            animation: spinny 2s linear infinite;
            -webkit-animation: spinny 2s linear infinite;

        }

        @keyframes spinny {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
            }
            50% {
                transform: scale(1.2) rotate(180deg);
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(180deg);
            }
            100% {
                transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
                -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        @keyframes pulse {
           
             0% { 
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            
             @keyframes pulse1 {
           
             0% { 
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Animation Spinner</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
    
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="title">Spinner</p>
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but you just erased the border? I wanted the border to be there but not change in opacity. Sorry if I wasn't clear.